# Creating backend service with multiple umigs

Tags: https, backend

Need some help creating a backend service with multiple umigs by using terraform code. using the below code but not able to assign multiple umigs.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
resource "google_compute_backend_service" “test-bs" {
  project               = module.test.project_id
  name                  = "test-bs"
  provider              = google
  protocol              = "HTTPS"
  port_name             = "services"
  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL"
  timeout_sec           = 30
  enable_cdn            = false
  health_checks = [google_compute_health_check.test-hc.id]
  backend {
    group =“https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test/zones/us-east4-c/instanceGroups/umig-01"]
    , "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test/zones/us-east4-c/instanceGroups/umig-02"}

    balancing_mode  = "UTILIZATION"
    capacity_scaler = 1.0
```